# Unable to reference extender assembly Ajaxcontroltoolkit ASP.NET 4.0 Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 Professional and .Net framework 4.0.

I want to use AjaxControlToolkit

Am I doing it right?

1. File -> New WebSite
2. Right Click on my Project in Solution Explorer -> Manage NuGet Packages
3. Install AjaxControlToolkit
4. Drag & Drop Script Manager
5. Drag & Drop Textbox
6. TextBox -> Add extender -> whichever extender, IT FAILS.

> Unable to reference extender assembly ajaxcontroltoolkit version 4.1.51116.0, Culture=Neutral...

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I generally download the AJAX Control Toolkit from: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/
2. I then unzip them to a location like C:\DevelopmentDLLs\AJAX\v4.1.xxx.
3. I right click on the References folder in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer and click add reference.
4. I browse to my Ajax DLL and add it there.
5. If my AJAX extenders are not in the Toolbox, I simply right-click and Add Items..
6. I locate the DLL once more, and the selected the AJAX extenders I want to appear in my toolbox.

Also, make sure that the AJAX DLL you downloaded is unblocked after extracting it from the ZIP file.

[image]

Comment: Well it is not working...
It is interesting, that Editor works, but HTMLEditorExtender do NOT.

Comment: @blast3r Have you tried right-clicking on the downloaded AJAX DLL and right-clicking on it and made sure that it is unblocked.